# How to export sqlite3 database in mac xml xls file format programmatically in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, export, export-to-excel

How to export the sqlite3 database table in mac xml excel .xml and microsoft excel xsl xml spreadsheets format programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used Core Data to manage your DB just loop on the Entities and use a NSMutableString to build your document.
For MS Excel you can build an HTML  and it will be read too.

Comment: I have not used core Data and i want to export data from the app only and that also in .xls format.

Comment: I don't understand; if you need to load an XLS file you can build it as an HTML table so don't need to build an XML document. If you need exactly an XML file you can still loop on a cursor with data from your table and use an NSMutableString to add elements from your cursor